# How to check if the last page is active JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, styling

I have created buttons within JavaScript. Above these buttons, items are displayed. When I am on the first page, the button titled 'Back' is disabled.

When I am on the last page, the button titled 'Next' should be disabled.

I have this code:

```
const items = [
    {name: "item1"},
    {"name: item2"},
    {"name: item3"},
    {"name: item4"},
    {"name: item5"},
]
```

I have displayed the items using this code:

```
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

let pageIndex = 0;
let itemsPerPage = 3;

loadItems();
function loadItems() {
  content.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i = pageIndex * itemsPerPage; i < (pageIndex * itemsPerPage) + itemsPerPage; i++) {
    const item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = `
        <p>$item[i].name</p>
    `;
    content.append(item);
  }
  minusPage();
  loadPageNav();
  plusPage();
}

function loadPageNav() {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length / itemsPerPage; i++) {
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.classList.add('btn');
    button.innerHTML = i + 1;
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      pageIndex = e.target.innerHTML - 1;
      loadItems();
    });
    nav.append(button);
  }
}

function plusPage() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.innerHTML = "Next";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageIndex = pageIndex + 1;
    loadItems();
  });

  nav.append(button);
}

function minusPage() {
  nav.innerHTML = "";
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  button.innerHTML = "Back";
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageIndex = pageIndex - 1;
    loadItems();
  });
  nav.append(button);

  if (pageIndex === 0) {
    button.style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
  }
}
```

I now want to add a different colour to the Next button when the user is on the last page. How can I find out when the user is on the last page.

Comment: you can determine if a user is on the last page by tracking the current page number and comparing it to the total number of pages

Comment: Keep in mind your code doesn't disable the "Previous" button when on the first page. Your code crashes with the first `for` loop in loadItems, because it expects to find 3 items on the last page when there are only two. Try adding something to that loop that checks if your variable `i` is within the range [0,items.length) before trying to read the item at that index.

Comment: I do not have a set number of pages. My program automatically creates the required pages.